# ahk script tweak for 2 instances

Tags: script, autohotkey, multiple-instances

I’m trying to create two different hotkeys that launch two independent instances of an application. When the second one is open a “[2]” is added to the title of the Window, which is very useful to me.
But it is not working my below code. For example, when I open the second instance not only “[2]” is not appearing but also the first instance *without pre-number" won't launch.

How can I have the two hotkeys to open each one its one window, not depending to each other?

```
#1:: 
      IfWinExist Total Commander (x64) 8.51a - NP
      {
      WinWait Total Commander (x64) 8.51a - NP
      WinActivate
      }
      else
      Run c:\Program Files\Total Commander\TOTALCMD64.EXE,,Max
      {
      WinWait Total Commander (x64) 8.51a - NP
      WinActivate
      }
 Return

 #2::  ; application title should show [2] weather the other is opened or not  ; corrected indentation here
      IfWinExist [2] Total Commander (x64) 8.51a - NP
      {
      WinWait [2] Total Commander (x64) 8.51a - NP
      WinActivate
      }
      else
      Run c:\Program Files\Total Commander\TOTALCMD64.EXE,,Max
      {
      WinWait [2] Total Commander (x64) 8.51a - NP
      WinActivate
      }
    Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code blocks are a bit off I think, try this:

```
tc_title:="Total Commander (x64) 8.51a"
tc_path:="c:\Program Files\Total Commander\TOTALCMD64.EXE"

#1:: 
IfWinExist %tc_title%
    {
     WinActivate %tc_title%
    }
else IfWinNotExist %tc_title%
    {
     Run %tc_path%,,Max
     WinWait %tc_title%
     WinActivate
    }
Return
#2::
IfWinExist [2] %tc_title%
    {
     WinActivate [2] %tc_title%
    }
else IfWinNotExist [2] %tc_title%
    {
     Run %tc_path%,,Max
     WinWait [2] %tc_title%
     WinActivate
    }
Return
```

See http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Block.htm for more information